# SQL code for sum by grouping by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have this query (except for the last column) and what I want to do is the last columns followed by this logic:

if the `code` column is between 101 and 111 then we sum the values on `VLR1` grouped by the `PERIOD` column and subtract by only one row of `VLR2` (it can be the first since all the rows in one period are the same).

| PERIOD | CODE | VLR1 | VLR2 | DESIRED COLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 101 | 1000 | 100 | 5900 |
| 2019-01 | 101 | 2000 | 100 | 5900 |
| 2019-01 | 103 | 3000 | 100 | 5900 |
| 2019-01 | 722 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I have more columns on my query than these displayed above and this is my current code:

(I know the second line of my code is not right as it is now but that is the "idea", I just don't know how to fix it)

```
SELECT X.PERIOD, X.CODE, X.VLR1, X.VLR2,
(SELECT SUM(X.VLR1) - X.VLR2) GROUP BY PERIOD) 
FROM
(
    ...
) X
ORDER BY X.PERIOD
```

Comment: What is period? Presumably that is a string? It's certainly not a date.

Comment: Yes, it is a string as it is displayed on the table

Comment: Please tag your question with proper dbms.  It's useless if someone posts a working answer with the wrong dbms.

Comment: What if `VLR2` was not the same on each row, presumably it could be otherwise your data model is flawed?

Comment: I am sure that the `VLR2` will have the same value if they are on rows that have the `PERIOD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following query using a *windowed sum* work for you?

```
select *,
  Sum(vlr1) over(
    partition by period, 
                 case when code >= 101 and code <= 111 then 1 end
  ) - vlr2 Desired_Column
from t
order by period, code, Vlr1;
```

See [sample Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7mNy21gB)